# Past continuous vs Past Perfect continuous

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

**When I was taking a Biology class in 2005, we were assigned to do an animal experiment.**

So what is wrong with that sentence? I am using a free grammar checker website and it says the tense is wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid what's wrong is that you are using a free grammar checker website. (Not trying to be snarky, 'tis the truth.) I am also not quite sure where Past Perfect Continuous comes in. I am not seeing it anywhere. Is that what the grammar checker suggests?

Comment: Assuming 'class' means course here (although in the UK 'taking a class' usually means you're teaching the said group), there is a mismatch between 'I' and 'we' that is strictly an anacoluthon. But then most elliptical sentences are. Perhaps 'when' is seen as inappropriate:  'At one point during the biology course I attended in 2005, we students were required to carry out an animal experiment.'

Comment: @Edwin: I don't see anything wrong with the mismatch between "I" and "we" here.

Comment: The referent for 'we' is ill defined (in fact not mentioned) (one would guess it's the members of the - er, class, but it could be all those following the biology National Curriculum, say). Mind you, my suggested re-write above does not totally address this ambiguity. Writing in the UK, I'd put  '... our class were required . . .'.

Comment: As @RegDwigнt points out, ***NO*** automatic grammar checker **ever** gives correct results. Don't use them, don't trust them, don't believe what they say. They are just crappy string-based software with no connection to real English grammar. Since people will believe anything about language and "correctness", anybody can write this stuff with any output and people will use it and trust it. This is not as good as learning English grammar.

Comment: @Edwin: the "our" in "our class" is just as lacking in referent as the "we" in the OP's sentence.

Comment: @Peter I'm not referring to grammaticality a la Chomsky, but to what most people would regard as satisfactory detail. 'When I was a youth, we often went to the cinema' is grammatical, of course, but needs further contextualisation to be acceptable as a meaningful statement.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which grammar checker you used and the exact error statement it gave you. I checked the sentence in three free online tools, as well as in Microsoft Word. None of them indicated any mistake.

Comment: I used grammarly.com, @Shoe. Also I paid money, it was not free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If grammar checker were perfect, there'd be no need for ELU.  You've identified a bug in the program you are using.  There is no error.